# Altium: Correct pin electrical type for Vin and Vout pins on schematic symbol

Tags: altium

I have created schematic symbol for a voltage regulator in Altium. It has pin for voltage input and pins for voltage output.

[image]

Do I set the electrical type to power for all pins or do I set the vin to Input and Vout to output? I could just set all of them to passive as well. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting to do circuit simulations, or just designing the PCB?

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://live.altium.com/signin?prmGotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.live.altium.com%2F%23%2F

Answer (score 3):

When you validate your project the settings in the Connection matrix comes into play:

[image]

It can't catch all the errors you make but it might save you from some mistakes. I would set them to Power, then check any warnings I get. If the warnings and errors were just annoying I would set the pins to Passive.

If you want to use theese properties depends on your design environment. If you're a single inexperienced designer, you might want some extra help from the tool. If you are an inexperienced designer in a big team you might waive the ERC warnings and let the review board catch the errors. An engineer with many years of designing might find the Altium settings a nuisance and set everything to Passive because the errors the ERC can check (and generate) doesn't add any value.

Edit:
Regarding simulations, I have never used Altium for simulations. At all the places I have worked the simulations have always been done by recreating the circuit in another tool, Hyperlynx, LTSpice etc.

Comment: Based on the default table, setting both pins to power should be fine and generate no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with designing a PCB and not running any circuit simulations within Altium, use **Passive** for all pins. The electrical rules check (ERC) will consider the pin types and their connections, thus if you don't have other details in place for the simulator, the ERC will generate warnings and/or errors which can become obstacles for simple PCB design.

There are extensions to Altium which will use this information as well, so the real answer is "it depends" based on what you or your company wants to do. For me, I do simulations outside of Altium so almost all of my component library is set up with passive pins (a huge task to fix if we ever decide to change it).

Check the [official documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/creating-schematic-symbol#!creating-a-symbol) for more information (though it does not really cover the pin electrical type in any great detail).

Comment: I did check the documentation and did not find anything helpful specifically for this query. I thought Altium simulation capabilities are terrible and no one will ever want to use it.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but there is at least one extension which is useful for checking power dissipation and current versus track widths. I forget the name of it, but at some point I've needed to (as a minimum) specify a few power pins on things. I just don't want my recommendation to lead to heartache later; but I can attest to using "passive" for everything and have completed dozens of successful boards.

Comment: ok, just one more thing, since circuits can get quite large and complex I believe we would only ever simulate a small part. This means that we could just recreate that small part of our design in spice and simulate it. Is this how you do it?

Comment: @quantum231 Exactly. We simulate portions of circuits as needed, not entire PCB designs.

Comment: So what did Altium expect the people to do, not use SPICE and other tools like Simetrix and just rely on Altium for the simulation purpose?

Comment: I would encourage you to not place all the pins as passive since it is really useful to prevent having floating inputs and other thing like that. On a complex design, it can really be really easy to miss a bad connection (as output in output or floating input).  In that instance, I'd place both as power.

Comment: @Julien Passive vs power doesn't matter if the ERC is set correctly to warn about non-connected pins of either type. The installation default for both is actually set to treat them the same for non-connected status (not reported).

Comment: Fair. I encourage people to set them all anyway, but the matrix doesn't make much difference in that case. The reason I encourage people from  setting them to the right type is that many don't know when it really matters. But in that instance, you are right, either don't really matter (but, to enter my libs, it would be properly set)!

Comment: @Julien I agree completely! My company requires an ERC directive be set on _all_ unused pins so they will generate a non-connected warning/error if they were not explicitly set to "do not connect" in the schematic. I'd forgotten that we'd set passive and power pins the same (I reverted to installation defaults temporarily to check).